# rendering JSON String as JSON Using JAXB within jersey

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey

Given a class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyClass {
    private Boolean flag1;
    private String json;
    ...
}
```

Can I add an annotation that will cause the JSON to become part of the rendered JSON without being escaped as a string?

For example, if the object has `flag1=true` and `json="{"a":5}"` I want to get:

```
{"flag":true,"json":{"a":5}}
```

instead of:

```
{"flag":true,"json":"{\"a\":5}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own marshaller to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Provider to change default behaviour of JSONJAXBContext. See http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e865

```
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException; 

import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext;

@Provider
public class CustomWoodwingOutputJSONContextProvider implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

private JAXBContext context;
private Class<?>[] types = { MyClass.class };

public CustomWoodwingOutputJSONContextProvider() throws JAXBException {
    this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().build(), types);
}

public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.types.length; i++)
        if (this.types[i].equals(objectType))
            return context;

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: This is a bit too much for me at the moment. I hoped for something more simple. Still maybe it will help someone else. For my own needs I just left it as a string And I do the json parsing on the client side.